# Div specific styles cancel out styles

Tags: html, css, styles

In my CSS file I have some general styles for links that I want to keep universal, such as no text decoration when visited, and a color change when hovered, but I want some specific styles on my navigation bar at the top like the font being white all the time (Black nav bar but white everything else so I want to see the links), but the **#navBar** specific styles on my links seem to make any other general styles on links cancel out, such as the color change to #1d99ff in **a:hover**, or the text-decoration: none in both **a:link** and **a:visited** as shown below.

```
a:link{
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
a:hover{
    color: #1e99ff
}

#navBar{
    text-align: center;
    word-spacing: 100px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #000000;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}   
#navBar a:link{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#navBar a:visited{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Shouldn't the general link styles be applied to all links, and the ID specific ones take those styles and add the ones specified? Or do I have to redefine the styles already defined before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you want to override a single item's style for instance, you should do it via html since it will simply override all conflicts.

```
<div style="color: #000;">
```

Comment: If I change the navBar link's colors to white in HTML (within the link tag), it still does not change the color on hover. Also changing color in the div tag does not accomplish anything.